# Regex from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have this code:

```
<div class="dealOnContainer">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                product_countdown('25092', $('counterbox90'));
            </script>

</div>
```

and i'm trying whole day to catch seconds from this script ('25092') with regex but there is no idea.
also i'm trying:

```
preg_match('#product_countdown(.*?)/#is', $string, $matches); 
  list($sekunde) = $matches;
  $data['sekunde'] = $sekunde;
```

but doesnt work. Please Help me. (sorry for my english)

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what you're trying to do. It looks like you're using PHP, but you didn't tag this question with `php`. I don't see any xpath at all, either.

Answer (score 2):

You're matching from `product_countdown('` until the nearest `/`, and that's much more than just the seconds part you're trying to match.

Try

```
#product_countdown\(\'(.*?)'\)#is
```

Now the `.*?` is forced to match between `product_countdown('` and `')`.

Comment: If that parameter only ever contains a single integer number, use `#product_countdown\(\'(\d*)'\)#i` instead. That would be even better.

Comment: The `s` is unnecessary since there are no dots in the regex (and the `s` parameter modifies how dots are interpreted).